# Rails+Facebox: pop-up-window doesn't work

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I followed the source code form the [rails3-devise-bootstrap-example](https://github.com/jehughes/rails3-devise-bootstrap-example) to get my devise-login-page (that normally - without AJAX - works fine) in a popup window.

When I click on the login link nothing happens. The logfile tells me

```
Started GET "/facebox/fb_login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-09 19:15:0
  Processing by FaceboxController#fb_login as JS
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/_new.html.erb (1155.0ms)
  Rendered facebox/fb_login.js.erb (1251.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1509ms (Views: 1508.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But no login-pop-up-window appears.

Here is the login link in my **index.html.erb** file

```
<%= link_to 'Login', fb_login_path, :remote => true %>
```

That starts my **fb_login.js** file

```
$.facebox('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'devise/sessions/new') %>')
```

and should open **_new.html.erb** that looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

but it doesn't. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by myself . Under assets/javascripts I had to define

```
jQuery ->
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()

# facebox - make modal

$(document).bind "loading.facebox", ->
  $(document).unbind "keydown.facebox"
  $("#facebox_overlay").unbind "click"
```

in a js.coffee file.